# Can we compute most significant digit of a binary number in O(1) on RAM model?

Tags: algorithms

Consider we use a RAM model with word length w (or if you really want a more exact model, you can use [Knuth's MMIX](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/mmop.html) [instructions](https://mmix.cs.hm.edu/doc/instructions-en.html) with w-bit numbers).

Given a number n, we want to compute the most significant digit.

For least significant digit, this is pretty easy:
$n - 10 \lfloor {n\over{10}} \rfloor$

which is O(1).

If we wanted to compute the most significant *bit* (instead of digit), we could shift bits right and compare with zero, and can do that in O(lg w) (binary search for rightmost 1 bit).

We can go the same for digits by diving by 10 until the number becomes less than 10, linear search in O(w).

Is there a similar O(1) algorithm for computing the most significant digit? If not, can we prove that?

Update:
here is an algorithm that is NOT O(1):

$\lfloor {n \over{10^{\lfloor\log n\rfloor}}} \rfloor$

as exp and log are not O(1).

Comment: Are you assuming that $n$ fits into a single word?  Otherwise, finding the least significant digit cannot be done in $O(1)$ time.  It might be a good idea to specify what operations/instructions you are assuming are made available by the processor.  Presumably $+,-,\times,/$.  Anything else?  A $\log$ function? A ffs (find-first-set)/clz/bsrl instruction?

Comment: (I can tell the most significant binary digit of a number in O(1).)

Comment: I suppose my first thought was the same as @greybeard's. The point is that's it is unneeded and potentially confusing to say that it's a binary number, when binary doesn't relate to anything important and the task is about a decimal digit.

Comment: 0 iff 0. Else for the MSD base B > 2, take the fractional part of the number's logarithm base B, add 1, exponentiate and take the floor value: How fast *and accurate* can your RAM determine that logarithm? Proving non-existence of an algorithm requires discussing algorithms, cf. halting problem.

Comment: yes, fits in a word.

Comment: for operations, if you want an exact model, assume Knuth's MMIX instruction set.

Comment: exp and log are not O(1) afaik in RAM models, e.g. MMIX.

Comment: MMIX is a 64-bit model.

Comment: The answer really depends on the operations that you allow. You can get the MSB using `x < ~x`, performing an unsigned comparison.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thank you. can you expand and post it as an answer?